# N Rows data to column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

Below is my table `Owner` with two columns, `[Owner Name]` and `Address` data:

```
Owner Name      Address
-----------------------
CURRENT OWNER   AD1
CURRENT OWNER   AD2
CURRENT OWNER   AD3
CURRENT OWNER   AD4
```

I need below output:

```
Owner Name  Address1    Address2    Address3    Address4
----------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT OWNER   AD1      AD2         AD3          AD4
```

Addresses can be more than 1000 against owner name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL and `PIVOT` to do this:

```
DECLARE
    @MaxAddresses int = (SELECT MAX(C) FROM (SELECT COUNT([Owner Name]) C FROM [Owner] GROUP BY [Owner Name]) Q)
    , @AddressHeaders varchar(max) = ''
    , @n int = 1

WHILE @n <= @MaxAddresses
BEGIN

    SET @AddressHeaders = @AddressHeaders + ', Address' + CAST(@n as varchar)

    SET @n = @n + 1

END

SET @AddressHeaders = STUFF(@AddressHeaders, 1, 2, '')

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) =
    '
        SELECT [Owner Name], ' + @AddressHeaders + '
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    [Owner Name]
                    , [Address]
                    , ''Address'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Owner Name] ORDER BY [Address]) AS varchar) AddressHeader
                FROM [Owner]
            ) Q
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX([Address])
                FOR AddressHeader IN (' + @AddressHeaders + ')
            ) P
    '

EXEC (@SQL)
```